# Full source code disclosure through git files (GIT)

Tags: git, .htaccess, version-control, bitbucket

Few days back got an email from an anonymous (self called expert) regarding the git Source Code visibility issue for my Private repository.

The content of the email was as below.

======================================

## Introduction

I have found a critical security issue in your website, which needs your attention as soon as possible, I am sending details about the issue below. Please read all the details carefully.

## Issue

As you know the website use a git repository to store its source code, I found that the /.git endpoint is not properly handled on the website. So, the content of the git objects is visible publicly to anyone. As we can easily calculate the SHA-1 hash of the next file. with a simple script any one can download the whole source code of the website.

Here are some examples.

1. http://www.example.com/.git/HEAD
2. http://www.example.com/.git/config
3. http://www.example.com/.git/logs/HEAD

## Impact

Any one without authorisation can download and view the whole source code of the website, and a malicious attacker could use to perform various things. Website defacement or Cryptojacking are some of them.

## Proof of Concept

I am attaching screenshots of the source code collected, from repository as proof of concept. Please do check the attachments.

(The screen shot contain my website folder structure)

## Fix

The fix is to properly lockdown /.git files on the site, it can be down by editing your .htaccess file and httpf.conf file if you use apache.

============================================

I managed to locked down the .git folder using htaccess.  I would like to ask was it the bug from Git or my repository was lacking some thing.

Comment: Don't deploy using git. Copy the files over using another method.

Comment: You mean to say i should not use git in my projects ?

Comment: I didn't say not to use git. However, in my opinion, git shouldn't be used as a deployment strategy. If you do want to use git, [take a look here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45452/is-using-git-for-deploying-a-bad-practice)